# Python 2.7: Running a python file within a package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have three folders:

```
/main
    __init__.py
    main.py
    /p1
        __init__.py
        p1.py
    /p2
        __init__.py
        p2.py
```

However some parts of `p1` depend on `p2` and the way in which I import `p2` from `p1` is by using an absolute package and not a relative one:

```
from main.p2.p2 import p2class
```

The problem arises when I want to run `p1` individually by typing in:

```
cd main\p1 
python p1.py
```

However, it says:

```
ImportError: No module named main.p2.p2
```

How can I run it individually?

Sources for the files are shown below:

`main\p1\p1.py`:

```
from main.p2.p2 import p2print

def p1print():
    print "p1 printing"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p2print()
    p1print()
```

`main\p2\p2.py`:

```
def p2print():
    print "p2 printing"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p2print()
```

Comment: If you want to run the code exactly the way you say, you can set `PYTHONPATH` for your environment to `absolute path till main`. I assume this should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From outside of the /main directory, run it using `python -m`.

```
➜ python -m main.p1.p1
p2 printing
p1 printing
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import from `p2.p2` instead of `main.p2.p2` since the base package is inside main. If you wish to do `main.p2.p2`, you will have to insert the path of the `main` folder into `sys.path`

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to avoid doing, as this approach will work in some cases but not in all. Changing the code to support one case but not the other seemed like a bad idea